# Keeping the focus on an html form in spite of tab key

Tags: html, webforms

I am trying to create a webform in HTML, and if needed javascript. In this webform one should be able to enter source code, so to do that comfortably I would like one to be able to enter tabs. 
Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: If the rest of your page doesn't accept <tab> in its normal context, the fact that your textbox allows <tab> as input won't overcome the irritation your users will feel while using the rest of the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to capture the onKeyDown event.  If the keycode is equal to the tab key, then replace the tab with 3 spaces or something like that.

**UPDATE:**
I tested this in firefox 3.  Allows you to type a tab without loosing focus.  Just be careful b/c this code will just append a tab character to the end of the text box.  Thus, if the user types a tab in the middle of text, tab will still appear at the end.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function kH(e) 
    {
        //capture key events
        var pK = document.all? window.event.keyCode:e.which;

        //if target is textbox and key is tab
        if(e.target.type=='text' && pK==0)
        {
            //append tab to end of target value
            e.target.value = e.target.value + "\t";

            //Cancel key event
            return false;
        }

    }

   document.onkeypress = kH;
   if (document.layers) document.captureEvents(Event.KEYPRESS);

</script>
</head>
<form>
    <input type='text' id='txtTest' name='txtTest'></input>
</form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a good way...that's why stackoverflow makes you do 4 spaces and uses a special library to interpret 4-space indented stuff as code. I suppose if you really wanted to use tabs you could do an onBlur event handler which just gave focus back to the window, and an onKeyDown event handler that inserted 4 spaces whenever the TAB key was pressed.

Comment: That is what I figured. Some of my parsers use similar coding style.

Answer (score 0):

You could go for an "indent" button on the toolbar. When it is pressed, it either inserts a tab if nothing is selected, or indents the selection.